# Best practice for MySQL data archiving

Tags: mysql, database

I have a MySQL database with more than 2 years of data.

It is not required to have more than 6 months of data to run the application. We may need the rest of the data for historical reporting, which is rarely used.

I am thinking about two models as below.

1. Model 1

   - Keep 6 months of data on the live server
   - Keep complete data on archiving server
2. Model 2

   - Keep 6 months of data on the live server
   - Keep the rest of the data on archiving server (Complete data - 6 months data)

Please help me to identify which is the best model from the above 2 options or is there a better model.

Also, do help me if there is an inbuilt mechanism with MySQL server for data archiving.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What data size are we talking about?

Comment: The more backups and copies of data, the better, so model 1. However, keeping the archieve completely up-to-date can be a problem. So, keep it as up-to-date as reasonably possible. And make a backup, again, and again. As far as I am aware the free version of MySQL is not very good at archiving, depending on your database type, for professional tools you would need to pay.

Comment: Can you suggest any good archiving solutions?

Comment: paul-spiegel, It's about 100GB